# Post Data for a site in httpwebrequest

Tags: vb.net

so i am trying to login to a website using httpwebrequest. the post data i got from a http debugger is [image: > here <]

code i am trying is:

```
Dim postData As String = "securitycheck=85b39cc89f04bc1612ce9d0c384b39ca&do_action=log_into_system&jump_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreamstime.com%2F&uname=jawademail&pass=jawadpass"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://www.dreamstime.com/securelogin.php"), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST"
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = "https://www.dreamstime.com/login.php"
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

        RichTextBox1.Text = thepage
```

thsi code does not seem to post data in website i get referer page code in richtextbox after running the code.

Comment: Likewise it's important that you give feedback to the replies you've gotten (even if they're just comments) so that the people that are trying to help you know _if_ what they've suggested have been of any help to you _and_ that they're not just wasting their time. Please look this over, otherwise people might start deciding _not_ to help you. Thank you!

Comment: i am new to forum & unaware of many things. i will take this in mind for future.

Comment: Good, but you ought to take action regarding your current posts as well. -- As for your issue, se my answer below.

Comment: When you login, you need to extract this security token and apply it to subsequent requests.

Comment: @JohnyL can you elaborate a little more and apply iy to my code. thanks in advance

Comment: Alas, it's impossible without knowing login and password information...

Comment: @JohnyL what if i provide you login information.

Comment: I could try to get this token.

Comment: @JohnyL whats your email or skype anything to contact you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174161/discussion-between-johnyl-and-rana-jawad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First GET the page, find the "securitycheck" in its source and extract it.

Combine it with the rest of your data then send it with POST.

Ok so I felt like trying:

```
    Dim LoginData As String
    Dim LoginCookies As New CookieContainer() 'Move this outside of sub/function so you can use it later
    Dim LoginRequest As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.dreamstime.com/login.php")
    LoginRequest.CookieContainer = LoginCookies
    LoginRequest.KeepAlive = True
    LoginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    LoginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0"
    Dim LoginResponse As HttpWebResponse = LoginRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim LoginResponseRead As StreamReader = New StreamReader(LoginResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Using LoginResponseRead
        Do
            Dim line As String = LoginResponseRead.ReadLine
            If line.Contains("var securitycheck=") Then
                LoginData = "securitycheck=" & line.Substring(line.IndexOf("=") + 2, line.LastIndexOf("'") - line.IndexOf("=") - 2)
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End Using
    Dim byteData As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(LoginData)
    LoginRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.dreamstime.com/securelogin.php")
    LoginRequest.CookieContainer = LoginCookies
    LoginRequest.Method = "POST"
    LoginRequest.KeepAlive = True
    LoginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    LoginRequest.Referer = "https://www.dreamstime.com/login.php"
    LoginRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
    LoginRequest.ContentLength = byteData.Length
    Dim postreqstream As Stream = LoginRequest.GetRequestStream()
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
    postreqstream.Close()
    LoginResponse = LoginRequest.GetResponse()
    LoginResponseRead = New StreamReader(LoginResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim thepage As String = LoginResponseRead.ReadToEnd
    'Now with GET request grab whatever you want, DON'T forget to use cookie.
```

Result

```
>>>securitycheck=183d5abdb01f288aacbe5b2893555ec5


    Dim email As String = "something"
    Dim password As String = "somethingelse"
    LoginData &= "&do_action=log_into_system&jump_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreamstime.com%2F&uname=" & email & "&pass=" & password

   >>>securitycheck=183d5abdb01f288aacbe5b2893555ec5&do_action=log_into_system&jump_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dreamstime.com%2F&uname=something&pass=somethingelse
```

There, practically done.

Comment: that worked for securitycheck now for logging in i have to make again http webrequest (my code in question)

Comment: Just continue with LoginRequest = create... method=post, you already have that part of code, you don't even need all of it.

Comment: come to chat for a min please

Comment: I don't know where chat is.

Comment: can you come skype? or email?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174279/discussion-between-cruled-and-rana-jawad).

Comment: Updated code. Didn't really want to do it, as it's better if you figure it out on your own, but oh well.

Comment: check this out                                                                                                                   https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174279/discussion-between-cruled-and-rana-jawad

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at this myself and it appears that with every login request a token is sent that identifies your "session", specifically:

```
securitycheck=85b39cc89f04bc1612ce9d0c384b39ca
```

This token changes every time you login, and if it isn't valid the site redirects you back to the login page, asking you to login again.

Sites usually do this to prevent [**Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). This means that you will most likely not be able to login to this site *without* using an actual web browser.

Comment: @RanaJawad : I don't know, I don't know what the website expects. However I just noticed that you said: _"i get referer page code in richtextbox after running the code"_ - You've set the referer to be `https://www.dreamstime.com/login.php`. Many websites use the `Referer` header to go back to the previous page that the user was on before login, which appears to be what this is doing. Which page's code are you expecting to get from this?

Comment: i basically want to check if post data is correct or not so, if login is wrong i should be getting page with incorrect user or pass or if its correct i should be getting account dashboard's code. i get this referer from http dubugger plugin as you can see the picture above.

Comment: @RanaJawad : The built-in `WebBrowser` control should be able to help you with this as long as you instruct it to use the latest version of the Internet Explorer engine.

Comment: If you know the address of the login page and the login page doesn't use angular or jquery, you can find the security code in the page and use it to send the request. But automatic a `WebBrowser` control to login seems more feasible.

Comment: @selfstudy : Sure, but that would require the additional step of parsing the page (assuming the token is present directly in the HTML code), which the `WebBrowser` control already does for you. So, like you say, it is easier to just let the WB take care of it :). In addition the pages (after login) will also be much easier to interact with.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that was tested and it works. It uses [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) rather WebClient (since it supports concurrent requests). This code is ***just a model*** since its main goal is to show the idea how to work with this site. There are additional explanations in comments. You also need to import `System.Web` dll.

```
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class TestForm

    Private Const URL_MAIN$ = "https://www.dreamstime.com"
    Private Const URL_LOGIN$ = "https://www.dreamstime.com/securelogin.php"
    Private Const URL_LOGOUT$ = "https://www.dreamstime.com/logout.php "
    Private Const USER_AGENT$ = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) " +
                                "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, Like Gecko) " +
                                "Chrome/68.0.3440.15 Safari/537.36 OPR/55.0.2991.0 " +
                                "(Edition developer)"

    Private Const LOGIN$ = "<USER_NAME>"
    Private Const PASS$ = "<USER_PASSWORD>"
    Private token$


    Private Async Sub OnGo() Handles btnGo.Click

        Dim html$

        Using client = New HttpClient()

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", USER_AGENT)

            Using req = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URL_MAIN)
                Using resp = Await client.SendAsync(req)
                    html = Await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                End Using
            End Using

            '// Search for security token
            Dim m = Regex.Match(
                    html,
                    "<input type=""hidden"" name=""securitycheck"" value=""(?'token'\w+)"">")

            If Not m.Success Then
                MessageBox.Show("Could not find security token.")
                Return
            End If

            '// Get security token
            token = m.Groups("token").Value

            '// Try to login.
            '// For logging to work, we need to use FormUrlEncodedContent class.
            '// Also we need to use it every time we do POST requests.
            '// No need for it for GET requests (as long as the HttpClient is the same).
            Using req = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, URL_LOGIN) With
            {
                .Content = GetFormData()
            }
                Using resp = Await client.SendAsync(req)
                    html = Await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                End Using
            End Using

            '// Go to main page to check we're logged in.
            '// "html" variable now MUST contain user's account name.
            Using req = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URL_MAIN$)
                Using resp = Await client.SendAsync(req)
                    html = Await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                End Using
            End Using

            '// Logout.
            '// "html" variable now MUST NOT contain user's account name.
            Using req = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URL_LOGOUT)
                Using resp = Await client.SendAsync(req)
                    html = Await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                End Using
            End Using

        End Using
    End Sub

    Function GetFormData() As FormUrlEncodedContent
        Return New FormUrlEncodedContent(New Dictionary(Of String, String) From
        {
            {"securitycheck", token},
            {"do_action", "log_into_system"},
            {"jump_to", ""},
            {"uname", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(LOGIN)},
            {"pass", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(PASS)}
        })
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: i was unable to check your solution, @CruleD gave shorter and simpler code. thanks for effort